# JDO no fields have been identified as primary key fields

Tags: java, jdo

I recently began to see JDO errors such as

```
Class X has been specified with an object-id class javax.jdo.identity.StringIdentity yet no fields have been identified as primary key fields.
```

My classes were using `javax.persistence.Id` annotations such as:

```
@Id
final private String key;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is due to marking key fields as final.  To fix, it was simply necessary to change the declaration to something like the following:

```
@Id
private String key;
```

Leaving this here for the benefit of posterity!